# How to hide scrollbar thumb in border radius element

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having problem with styling scroll bar on element with border-radius i've tried to use partent element with overflow: hidden but still it keeps going over. Is there a way to hide it?

```
<div class="match-container">
  <ul class="match-list">
    <li class="match-list__item">Hamlet</li>
    <li class="match-list__item">Ham</li>
    <li class="match-list__item">Hamster</li>
    <li class="match-list__item">Hamburger</li>
    <li class="match-list__item">Hammock</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
.match-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #131313;
  border-radius: 0 0 23px 23px;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top center;
  transition: 0.1s ease;
}

.match-container--active {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.match-container--active-scroll {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  padding-right: 3px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff41;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  width: 10px;
  background: #6d6d6d;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #999999;
}
```

It's looks like this.

[image]

Comment: `transform: scaleY(0);` i guess coz of this your code is showing no output. are you sure is this working code?

Comment: `.match-container  { scroll-padding: 0 0 10px 0;}`. try this. not sure if it fix it.

Comment: @CodeBug It's working, js is adding classes. that isn't all code, i only paste part that affects scroll and elements inside.

Comment: @HansakaSandaruwan Unfortunately, it's not working